# Is - `else if` - just syntactic sugar?

Tags: java, if-statement

In the past I have argued with some coder friends of mine who think that `else if` statements in Java are just syntactic sugar, and that anything done with `else if` can just be done with serial `if` instead.

But today I read something that I think might contradict that conclusively. Take for example the following code where `int x = 1`.

```
if(x >= 5){ System.out.println("First condition"); }
else if(x < 5){ System.out.println("Second condition"); }
else if (x < 2){ System.out.println("Third condition"); }
```

If you used seriel if statements (without the else) you get the output;

```
Second Condition
Third Condition
```

But with the above else if statements what you actually get is

```
Second Condition
```

Because `else if` statements don't fall through. Because the first `else if` ran, no other will run after it even if the conditions would be met. So to my question. Is there a way to accomplish this behaviour with serial standard if statements?

Comment: There might be, but why would you like to do that?

Comment: If you want the _fall through_, don't put the `else`s before the `if`s. A better way would be to use `switch..case`.

Comment: @RohitJain - It's just an academic query more than anything else. I will continue to use `else if` regardless in most situations I imagine.

Comment: Whoa, what the hell is with all the downvotes? I read the rules, this doesn't break any of them. I checked for other questions first, this one is original as far as I can see.

Comment: Guess what everyone says about Stack being hateful and elitist really is true. No one even wants to tell me what was wrong with the question.

Comment: Your question has (in sum) 0 votes. What´s the problem with it? In fact, with +3 and -3, you profited because upvotes count more than downvotes. I don´t know the reason for the downvotes, but not everyone here is that way.

Comment: @deviantfan - Guess I jumped the gun a little too soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`else if` *is* a syntactic sugar, but not for *serial* `if`s.

```
if (conditionA) {
} else if (conditionB) {
} else if (conditionC) {
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (conditionA) {
} else {
    if (conditionB) {
    } else {
        if (conditionC) {}
    }
}
```

The main gain from using the `else if` structure is the reduction in nesting, which makes the code much more readable.

---

**Edit**

As other answers have stated, in `java`, the above is not even proper syntactic sugar (though one might argue that an else block without curly braces for a single statement is a syntactic sugar by itself), there are other languages (like [`perl`](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/e/elseif.htm), and [`ruby`](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/ruby/ruby-if-else-if-command-syntax/) with `elsif`) where there is a proper syntax for just that.

Comment: It's not a syntactic sugar, brace is just not required, when there is only one statement.

Comment: It's not syntactic sugar. The 'if' in 'else if' starts another statement. I think what you said is like saying that 'else x = y+1;' is syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Val If you're referring to me, I am not attacking anyone, his answer is fine. It's just that I cannot agree with the term 'syntax sugar' here.

Answer (score 4):

I partly disagree with @Uri Agassi.

---

He is correct that you cannot (in general) rewrite:

```
   if (condition1) { System.out.println("First condition"); }
   else if (condition2) { System.out.println("Second condition"); }
   else if (condition3) { System.out.println("Third condition"); }
```

as

```
   if (condition1) { System.out.println("First condition"); }
   if (condition2) { System.out.println("Second condition"); }
   if (condition3) { System.out.println("Third condition"); }
```

(You can in cases where the conditions are *provably* mutually exclusive AND side-effect free, but that is not true in general.)

It is possible to write `if ... else` without an `else` but it requires extra flag variables; e.g.

```
   boolean f = false;
   if (condition1) { 
       System.out.println("First condition"); 
       f = true;
   }
   if (!f && condition2) { 
       System.out.println("Second condition"); 
       f = true;
   }
   if (!f && condition3) { 
       System.out.println("Third condition"); 
   }
```

---

But I disagree with him when he says that the first form is syntactic sugar ... for anything.  The Java grammar rules for an if statement are given in [JLS 14.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) as:

```
IfThenStatement:
    'if' '(' Expression ')' Statement
IfThenElseStatement:
    'if' '(' Expression ')' StatementNoShortIf 'else' Statement
IfThenElseStatementNoShortIf:
    'if' '(' Expression ')' StatementNoShortIf 'else' StatementNoShortIf
```

(The "no short if" stuff is to avoid "dangling else" ambiguity.  It is not relevant to my argumentation ...)

We get `else if` chaining by using an IfThenStatement or IfThenElseStatement as the Statement in an IfThenElseStatement.  Note that the grammar doesn't mention curly brackets.  The curly brackets only come in because a Statement can be a Block; see [JLS 14.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) again.

So based on what the Java grammar says, `if ... else if ...` is in fact just a natural form of the IfThenStatement syntax, not some special syntactic sugar.

Now if Java (hypothetically) >>also<< supported `elsif` like some other languages do, you could argue that the `elsif` form was syntactic sugar for `else if` ... but that is a different situation to this one.

---

> ... though one might argue that an else block without curly braces for a single statement is a syntactic sugar by itself

One would be incorrect :-)

It is a plain ordinary statement; see above.

It is *conventional* to always use curly brackets, but that is convention not syntax, and leaving out the curly brackets does not entail any sugar.

Comment: Can you add a source? Otherwise it is difficult to decide who is right. Because without knowing in-depth implementation of Java you or Uri could be right.

Comment: The source is the Java Grammar as defined in the Java Language Specification.  The rest is logical argumentation ... source >>me<<.  There is nothing in either my answer or Uri's answer that relates to implementation of the language.  It is all about how the language is specified.

Answer (score 1):

The general syntax of the **if statement** is:

`if (condition) statement`

or

`if (condition) statement1 else statement2`

Now to your question, that `if` in the `else if`
is the start of that `statement2` from the general form.

Answer (score -3):

> is there a way to accomplish this behaviour with serial standard if statements?

```
if(A){ System.out.println("a"); }
if(not A and B){ System.out.println("else B"); }
if(not A and not B and C){ System.out.println("else C"); }
```

Comment: @Val: That´s not the same. What if A and B are changed within the blocks?

Comment: Switch what? switch-case for serial accomplishment?

Comment: @deviantfan How not the same? What changed? Why changed? Why not the same?

Comment: @Val: With a if-elseif-elseif-else only one of the parts can be executed at maximum (doesn´t matter what code is in there). In your code, i could change A in the if(A)-part so that the next part would executed too...and so on.

Comment: @deviantfan And what? You can change my code leaving `println("a")` alone. This will never print neither "B" nor "C" ever. And what? Certainly, the two different pieces of code can be changed independently and, thus, loose the coherence. How does it make that two alternative implementatins, which have the same semantics are "different". How do you define equality? I can always define it the way that you have nothing identical.

Comment: @Val: I won´t go philosophical here. This here is a reason why there is an "else" too instead of "if" only, topic finished for me.

Comment: @Val - I am afraid he's right, if you replace `System.out.println("a");` with `A = false;` the second `if` statement can now run even if the first evaluated true, which is prevented with `else if`.

Comment: @user3449333 In this case you should precompute the conditions. The conditions must be immutable.

Comment: Sigh. No, conditions don´t have to be immutable. Just try it. You can call as many methods a you want (which may return different values all the times). You could even make conditions based on random numbers. And precomputing all conditions at the first if would break the language seriously. It´a very useful feature that condition (parts) are evaluated in a certain order at certain times